# Is there any way to programmatically connect to google drive, means without user interaction, without Oauth and just email and password

Tags: java, oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am working on a project. I want to integrate Google Drive and Drop Box in this. Can any one tell me how I apply operations on Drive data without user authentication
Just using email and password,
Or any other way to connect programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to understand is that Google drive data is private user data. In order to access private user data you need the permission of either the owner or someone that has access to the data.

The only way to get access is to use Oauth2 and request the users consent.

I recommend following the official [Drive java quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/java)

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/* class to demonstarte use of Drive files list API */
public class DriveQuickstart {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Google Drive API Java Quickstart";
    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    /** Directory to store authorization tokens for this application. */
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(DriveScopes.DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = DriveQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        if (in == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Resource not found: " + CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        }
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
        //returns an authorized Credential object.
        return credential;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the names and IDs for up to 10 files.
        FileList result = service.files().list()
                .setPageSize(10)
                .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name)")
                .execute();
        List<File> files = result.getFiles();
        if (files == null || files.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No files found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Files:");
            for (File file : files) {
                System.out.printf("%s (%s)\n", file.getName(), file.getId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand this, It is good when a person is interacting with it if a program want to interact then how is this possible ?

Comment: The only other option would be if its a google workspace user then you could have the admin of your workspace account grant you delegation and you could use a service account.     If you will only ever be accessing an account that you personally own and control you could also use a service account.    But if this is a standard gmail user of your app then You cant if this is a users data you need their permission.  Once they have granted you permission once then you can access it though the refresh token that you are granted.

Comment: Thank you so much Dalm To. Your information is very useful for me.